Next-themes doesn't change theme
I am using next-themes in my project to enable dark-mode. Theme changes based on the system preferences due to attribute="class". The icons change on click but the theme doesn't.
==> _app.tsx

import '@/styles/globals.css';
import type { AppProps } from 'next/app';
import { ThemeProvider } from 'next-themes';

export default function App({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
    return (
        <ThemeProvider defaultTheme="system" attribute="class">
            <Component {...pageProps} />
        </ThemeProvider>
    );
}



==> ThemeToggle.tsx
import { useTheme } from 'next-themes';
import { SunIcon, MoonIcon } from './icons';
import clsx from 'clsx';

const ThemeToggle = ({ className }: { className?: string }) => {
    const { theme, setTheme } = useTheme();

    return (
        <button id="home" className={clsx('z-50 cursor-pointer', className)}>
            {theme === 'dark' ? (
                <div onClick={() => setTheme('light')}>
                    <SunIcon className="mt-7 md:mt-11 h-6 w-6 fill-dark-day" />
                </div>
            ) : (
                <div onClick={() => setTheme('dark')}>
                    <MoonIcon className="mt-7 md:mt-11 h-6 w-6 fill-dark-night" />
                </div>
            )}
        </button>
    );
};

export default ThemeToggle;



==> Header.tsx
import Navbar from './Navbar';
import ThemeToggle from './ThemeToggle';

const Header = () => {
    return (
        <div className="flex flex-row justify-end mr-2 lg:mr-40">
            <Navbar />
            <ThemeToggle />
        </div>
    );
};

export default Header;

I tried the example implementation provided by next-themes, but had the same issue.
I also inspected the page to look at the local storage - theme variable is changing appropriately, but dark-mode is always set to false.

If you are uisng tailwindcss for dark mode you have to use the dark keyword to add styles when ever the darkmode is enabled like
<div className="bg-white dark:bg-black"></div>

When in light mode the color will be white and in the dark mode the background will be black.
